# Direct Download CSV file in IE 10 Open the file instead of download it

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I have a link to download a file from the server like this:

```
<a id="downloadCSVFile" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="parent.document.location = 'CSVFile.csv';">Download</a>
```

And i try this:

```
<a id="downloadCSVFile" runat="server" href="CSVFile.csv">Download</a>
```

now my problem is that **ONLY IE10 open the file instead of download it**!!!!

**Note:** I am using i-frame

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your server.

You need to put the correct headers when serving the file, notably `Content-Disposition` of the following form:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, but where to put it? i'm not create the file in javascript, the file is already in the server, and i have many file with other extensions and works fine